# Python tweepy script crashes after a period of time running. It gives 'Connection broken: IncompleteRead(10 bytes read)'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

I created a twitter monitor and it works fine but after a while the program crashes with the follow error

```
File "/home/server/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 380, in _error_catcher
    raise ProtocolError('Connection broken: %r' % e, e)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(10 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(10 bytes read))

File "/home/server/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 380, in _error_catcher
    raise ProtocolError('Connection broken: %r' % e, e)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(10 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(10 bytes read))
```

Heres my listener function, i also put the following catch errors but its not doing anything

```
from http.client import IncompleteRead as http_incompleteRead
from urllib3.exceptions import IncompleteRead as urllib3_incompleteRead

def Create_Listner():
    monitor_down('Started Twitter Bot Successfully!')
    listener = StreamPrinter()
    auth = OAuthHandler(Consumer_Key, Consumer_Secret)
    auth.set_access_token(Access_Token, Access_Token_Secret)
    #api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

    stream = Stream(auth, listener)
    try:
        stream.filter(follow=['3295423333', '59393368', '14886375'], is_async=True)
    except http_incompleteRead as e:
        #stream.disconnect()
        print("\n~~~ Restarting stream in 5 seconds... ~~~")
        monitor_down('Bot Crashed! Restarting Bot')
        time.sleep(5)
    except urllib3_incompleteRead as e:
        print("\n~~~ Restarting stream in 5 seconds... ~~~")
        monitor_down('Bot Crashed! Restarting Bot')
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53326879/twitter-streaming-api-urllib3-exceptions-protocolerror-connection-broken-i May solve your problem

Comment: by strip does he mean making a separate function and passing the data to that set function?

Comment: is there anyway to catch this error and restart the monitor?