# Twitter Streaming API: 'Connection broken: IncompleteRead'

Tags: python, spyder, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api, twitterapi-python

I am streaming some data from Twitter via the Streaming API on Python and Tweepy. The code can be seen below:

```
class TwitterStreamer():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def stream_tweets(self, twitter_data_title, key_words):
        # This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
        listener = StreamListener(twitter_data_title)
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secret_key)
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret_token)
        stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, listener)

        # This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords: 
        stream.filter(track=key_words)

class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, twitter_data_title):
        self.fetched_tweets_filename = twitter_data_title

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            print(data)
        
            with open(self.fetched_tweets_filename, 'a') as tf:
                tf.write(data)
            return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_data %s" % str(e))
        return True
      
    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    twitter_streamer = TwitterStreamer()
```

However, after some time I always get the error 'Connection broken: IncompleteRead'. I feel like this problem might be related to an earlier post ([Twitter Streaming API - urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53326879/twitter-streaming-api-urllib3-exceptions-protocolerror-connection-broken-i)), however, I do not understand how he solved the problem. How can I strip the function in a way this gets less computationally expensive?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This has been an ongoing problem when using the Twitter streaming API on Tweepy (I can't confirm if this happens anywhere else) that I have also experienced.

I've spent days trying to figure out how to fix it, but there is no real solution.

What I instead ended up doing was using a program supervisor called [Immortal](https://immortal.run), which will instantly restart a program if it stops. I've used it for more than a year now and have had no issues with it, it restarts my programs straight away.

After installation, you use it just by typing `immortal` and then adding the rest of your command, e.g.:

```
immortal python3 twitterbot.py
```

When your program inevitably raises the `IncompleteRead` error, Immortal will start it straight back up!